# Doublepulsar backdoor detection

Tags: windows

How to check if windows machines are running doublepulsar backdoor? I checked few machines and anti-virus is up to date,MS17-010 Patch is also installed but SIEM report says machines are infected.

Comment: Are you sure your SIEM is not giving you a false-positive?

Comment: I think so..i am just running some tests to prove it..